# Why is an alias target Boost::headers with the same name already existing?

Tags: cmake, boost

My CMakeLists.txt is including the `boost` library in the following way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

set(BOOST_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES filesystem iostreams log program_options system)
set(BOOST_ENABLE_CMAKE ON)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    Boost
    URL https://github.com/boostorg/boost/releases/download/boost-1.83.0/boost-1.83.0.7z
    USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD TRUE
    DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT FALSE
    FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS COMPONENTS ${BOOST_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES}
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Boost)
```

With that, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at _deps/boost-src/libs/headers/CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_library):
  add_library cannot create ALIAS target "Boost::headers" because another
  target with the same name already exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a *guess*: the target `Boost::headers` is created by `find_package(Boost)`, which is implicitly called because of `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS`. Could you create another CMake project, which doesn't use `FetchConent`, but just calls `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem iostreams log program_options system)`? For that project you could check Boost-related output of CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce it:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Base system
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install vim build-essential git wget

# Avoid encoding issue extracting Boost archive
RUN apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

# recent enough CMake
RUN wget https://apt.kitware.com/kitware-archive.sh && sh kitware-archive.sh
RUN echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ jammy main' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list >/dev/nul
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install cmake

# build
ADD CMakeLists.txt /
RUN cmake -B build .
```

`docker build .` prints: (click for full resolution)

[image]

```
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/12 : FROM ubuntu
---> 08d22c0ceb15
Step 2/12 : RUN # Base system
---> Running in 0303f897fedd
Removing intermediate container 0303f897fedd
---> 91d67f9a7b3c
Step 3/12 : RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install vim build-essential git wget
---> Running in 56bfea11e745
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [109 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [1036 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [44.0 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [1512 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [1282 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1576 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [49.8 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1304 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1572 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [32.6 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages [78.3 kB]
Fetched 28.8 MB in 1s (19.8 MB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu bzip2 ca-certificates cpp
cpp-11 dirmngr dpkg-dev fakeroot fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core g++
g++-11 gcc gcc-11 gcc-11-base gcc-12-base git-man gnupg gnupg-l10n
gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm less
...
...
...
Removing intermediate container a9c1b3a445ba
---> 8a0ee04eab28
Step 11/12 : ADD CMakeLists.txt /
---> 567d070ea4f1
Step 12/12 : RUN cmake -B build .
---> Running in 0d12728eab7c
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
code such as
project(ProjectName)

near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
line.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required() should be called prior to this top-level project()
call.  Please see the cmake-commands(7) manual for usage documentation of
both commands.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Boost: static libraries, MPI OFF, Python OFF, testing OFF
-- Boost: libraries included: filesystem;iostreams;log;program_options;system
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE

-- Performing Test BOOST_ATOMIC_TARGET_X86
-- Performing Test BOOST_ATOMIC_TARGET_X86 - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_ATOMIC_COMPILER_HAS_SSE2
-- Performing Test BOOST_ATOMIC_COMPILER_HAS_SSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_ATOMIC_COMPILER_HAS_SSE41
-- Performing Test BOOST_ATOMIC_COMPILER_HAS_SSE41 - Success
-- Boost.Context: architecture x86_64, binary format elf, ABI sysv, assembler gas, suffix .S, implementation fcontext
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_INIT_PRIORITY
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_INIT_PRIORITY - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_CXX20_ATOMIC_REF
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_CXX20_ATOMIC_REF - Failed
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_BLKSIZE
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_BLKSIZE - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_MTIM
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_MTIM - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_MTIMENSEC
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_MTIMENSEC - Failed
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_MTIMESPEC - Failed
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIMENSEC
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIMENSEC - Failed
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIMESPEC
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIMESPEC - Failed
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STATX
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_STATX - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_FDOPENDIR_NOFOLLOW
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_FDOPENDIR_NOFOLLOW - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_DIRENT_D_TYPE
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_DIRENT_D_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_POSIX_AT_APIS
-- Performing Test BOOST_FILESYSTEM_HAS_POSIX_AT_APIS - Success
-- Boost.Iostreams: ZLIB OFF, BZip2 OFF, LZMA OFF, Zstd OFF
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_TARGET_X86
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_TARGET_X86 - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_HAS_LOCK_FREE_ATOMIC_INT32
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_HAS_LOCK_FREE_ATOMIC_INT32 - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_COMPILER_HAS_SSSE3
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_COMPILER_HAS_SSSE3 - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_COMPILER_HAS_AVX2
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_COMPILER_HAS_AVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_HAS_NATIVE_SYSLOG
-- Performing Test BOOST_LOG_HAS_NATIVE_SYSLOG - Success
CMake Deprecation Warning at uild/_deps/boost-src/libs/predef/CMakeLists.txt:23 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.
Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
-- Boost.Thread: threading API is pthread
-- Configuring done (13.9s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: /build
Removing intermediate container 0d12728eab7c
---> c5d18a922a01
Successfully built c5d18a922a01
```

### UPDATE

After the comment adding the [context to reproduce](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c06625783b1d541) the issue, I found the cause.

The cause is that `FETCHCONTENT_TRY_FIND_PACKAGE_MODE` defaults to `OPT_IN` meaning `find_package` is invoked because `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS` is present. This finds the system Boost package which declares the ::headers` target.

Two ways to get around this:

1. drop `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS` with reference to the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html):

   > This option is for scenarios where the `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()` command may first try a call to `find_package()` to satisfy the dependency for `<name>`
2. set `FETCHCONTENT_TRY_FIND_PACKAGE_MODE` to `NEVER` before the content declaration:

   ```
   SET(FETCHCONTENT_TRY_FIND_PACKAGE_MODE NEVER)
   FetchContent_Declare(
       Boost
       URL https://github.com/boostorg/boost/releases/download/boost-1.83.0/boost-1.83.0.7z
       USES_TERMINAL_DOWNLOAD TRUE
       DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT FALSE
       FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS COMPONENTS ${BOOST_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES}
   )
   FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Boost)
   ```

Note:

- adding `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE` will not do anything if `find_package` finds Boost before the fetchcontent package is populated -- e.g. this fails: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55451090f10cffa7
- the value of `FETCHCONTENT_TRY_FIND_PACKAGE_MODE` **at the point of `FetchContents_Declare`** is what matters

More documentation is over at [Integrating With FindPackage](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#integrating-with-find-package)

Comment: This was a great approach, thanks, and it brought me to dig deeper.
Your example fails then, when you add `libboost-dev` to the list of packages installed in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I knew it :) It always help to create the minimal reproducer. I posted an update with analysis/workarounds that worked for me using [that Dockerfile](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c06625783b1d541)

Comment: This was a theory and practice. I made a `CMakeLists.txt` file, which was meant to be this minimal reproducible example, but forget to consider the environment it was running in.
This was even a devcontainer and, whyever, I did not consider the two cases that either `libboost` is already installed or not and further, that it could be installed with the `-dev` package and without. :-(

Comment: One point remaining.
At least something working I have now thanks to you , but it is not what was the original intention of the snippet.
The idea was that it uses the installed `boost` library, if installed with dev packages, but falls back to download it manually.
The reason for that is that I wanted to be able to create a nice package for Linux distributions, but still be able to compile (statically) for minimal embedded Linux systems and just copy the binary there.

Comment: It may be a QoI in Boost's CMake support worth reporting to the devs. The most straightforward workaround to me seems too manually check whether find_package succeeded and conditionally defaulting the Fetch Contt package only if not